# clicking through saved checkbox states

Tags: javascript

The below works to save the states of my checkboxes, then sets the items saved back to checked when called in my `load__()` function; however I need to instead of just setting to `checked`, I need to actually have them `.click()` through in my `load__()` function as the data is not being served otherwise.

```
  function checkSaver() { 
      user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));

      var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
      user.userAchkData = [];

      inputs.forEach(function(input){
        user.userAchkData.push({ id: input.id, checked: input.checked });
      });

      localStorage.setItem(username, JSON.stringify(user));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(user));

    }
```

---

```
    function load_() { 
      // get saved latest checkbox states, recheck
      user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));
      var inputs = user.userAchkData;

      inputs.forEach(function(input){ 
        if (input.id) { 
            // I need to click through the found checked here
            document.getElementById(input.id).checked = input.checked; 
        }
      });
```

---

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementById(input.id).click()`?

Comment: Wouldn't that just click all of them, regardless if they were checked or not?

Comment: You could check if you should click it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if they're checked and then programmatically trigger a click:

```
if (input.id) { 
   // I need to click through the found checked here
   const element = document.getElementById(input.id);
   element.checked = input.checked; 
   if (input.checked) element.click();
}
```

I fiddled around a bit and got to a simple working example for checking saved checkboxes. Maybe you can adapt this to your needs:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxes')) || new Array(3).fill(false);

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  [...container.children].forEach((child, i) => { child.checked = data[i]; });
});

container.onchange = ({ target }) => {
  data[target.dataset.id] = target.checked;
  localStorage.setItem('checkboxes', JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="0">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="1">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, upvote for taking a look; however this still didn't invoke the click

Comment: @CaptainRon Thanks for the upvote. I added some more code and maybe that will get you there.